# str object has no attribute 'id' - pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

My code for my personal assistant:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voice')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

# text to speech
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Error shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Samarth S\OneDrive\Desktop\AI Projects\AIVVA\3\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

This is my first python project and I am struck in the voices itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, the problem is specifically this line of  code where you call `getProperty` with **'voice'** as the parameter:

```
voices = engine.getProperty('voice')
```

Instead, you should call `getProperty` with **'voices'** as the parameter:

```
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
```

Calling `getProperty` with 'voices' will return a list of `pyttsx3.voice.Voice descriptor` objects which should make this line of code work:

```
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
```

Take a look at the [pyttsx3 engine documentation](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#module-pyttsx3.engine) for specifics.